# Convert string to timestamp in MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

How does one convert a string/varchar to a timestamp in MonetDB ?

Like this, but with millisecond precision (to six decimal places, ideally):

```
sql>select str_to_date('2008-09-19-18.40.09.812000', '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%6S');
+--------------------------+
| str_to_date_single_value |
+==========================+
| 2008-09-19               |
+--------------------------+
1 tuple (0.312ms)
```

I'm not sure whether str_to_date is built in or whether I created it ages ago and forgot.

```
create function str_to_date(s string, format string) returns date
external name mtime."str_to_date";
```

**Edit:** expected output something like

```
+---------------------------------+
| str_to_timestamp_single_value   |
+=================================+
| 2008-09-19 18:40:09.812000      |
+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monetdb time conversion functions are listed in :

- [Monetdb installation folder]\MonetDB5\lib\monetdb5\createdb\13_date.sql.

Besides the str_to_date function, there is a str_to_timestamp function.

The syntax of the format string follows [the MySQL one](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Example :

```
select sys.str_to_timestamp('2016-02-04 15:30:29', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```

Comment: for monet v1.7 it will throw `no such binary operator` error. Add schema name before function name `select sys.str_to_timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

The date/time specifiers might need to be changed:

```
select str_to_date('2008-09-19-18.40.09.812000','%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f')
```

output:

```
2008-09-19 18:40:09.812000
```

<sub>*monetdb could be different, although in standard SQL [these are the standard date specifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).</sub>

You could also use `date_format` in addition to `str_to_date`:

```
select date_format(str_to_date('SEP 19 2008 06:40:09:812PM','%M %D %Y %h:%i:%s:%f%p'),'%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%f');
```

output:

```
2008-09-19-18.40.812000
```

Comment: The date/time specifiers are fine, I'm really looking for something like `str_to_timestamp`.

Comment: Well monetdb has what is called `daytime` for dealing with precision time. If I remember correctly it's something like `daytime_tz_fromstr`. I guess I'm a little unclear, What is your expected output?